# Unstack pandas index without NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io 


data = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        ",x,t,t_cls,level\n0,70.0,4.472156319636573,med,level_0\n1,30.0,6.4012513032334235,med,level_1\n"
    )
).drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1)
```

I can unstack as follows :

```py
data.set_index("level", append=True).unstack(level=1)
```

Which gives:

|  | ('x', 'level_0') | ('x', 'level_1') | ('t', 'level_0') | ('t', 'level_1') | ('t_cls', 'level_0') | ('t_cls', 'level_1') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 70 | nan | 4.47216 | nan | med | nan |
| 1 | nan | 30 | nan | 6.40125 | nan | med |

As can be seen - there are `nan` values on every other col/row - I'd like to be able to have this "unstacked" to a single row rather than spread across two like it currently is.

For example:

[image]

And from there I can flatten the columns as needed.

## Edit - this *sort of* works

But is very ugly:

```py
(
    data.set_index("level", append=True)
    .unstack(level=1)
    .apply(lambda x: sorted(x.astype(str)), axis=0)
    .replace({"nan": np.nan})
    .dropna(how="all")
)
```

Gives:

|  | ('x', 'level_0') | ('x', 'level_1') | ('t', 'level_0') | ('t', 'level_1') | ('t_cls', 'level_0') | ('t_cls', 'level_1') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 70 | 30 | 4.47216 | 6.40125 | med | med |

Comment: ``data.set_index('level', append = True).unstack().bfill().dropna()``?

Answer (score 1):

Create a group variable by `level` first, then `pivot`:

```
data['g'] = data.groupby('level').cumcount()
data
#      x         t t_cls    level  g
#0  70.0  4.472156   med  level_0  0
#1  30.0  6.401251   med  level_1  0

data.pivot('g', 'level', ['x', 't', 't_cls'])
#            x                 t             t_cls        
#level level_0 level_1   level_0   level_1 level_0 level_1
#g                                                        
#0        70.0    30.0  4.472156  6.401251     med     med
```